# Overload JNI Method

Tags: java, java-native-interface, overloading

I have an existing JNI method with two parameters.  Been around for a while, in use, so I don't want to just change it lest the wrath of angry customers be unleashed.

But, I now need to make an adjustment.

So, I thought, make a second overloaded method with the extra parameter and deprecate the two-parameter version.  That part went fine, jar builds and runs with no issues.

The problem is in the C++ side... I defined two methods, one being a wrapper for the other (two parameter calls the three parameter version), but, when I went to export the two methods, I receive:

```
Error   1   error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function 'Java_com_xxx' not allowed
```

So, what do I do to keep the old method name and add a new method with new parameters?  Is this doable?

Comment: Run `javah` on your Java file declaring the native methods and you will see that you need two *different* `Java_com_xxx` functions.  The C-level declarations must be unique.

Comment: When you get this error ? In linking phase or during method invocation from Java code ?

Comment: Happens during the Linking phase.

Comment: @technomage, please make an answer out of your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `javah` on your Java file declaring the native methods and you will see that you need two different `Java_com_xxx` functions. The C-level declarations must be unique.