# How method Identified in JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

While I was developing , by mistakes I missed to add parameter in function. But same function in native jni call has parameter. But still it is calling exact method from java.

**Java class Demo.java**.

```
  package jniexamples.rmi;

class Demo {
    private native void jBoolean();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo().jBoolean();
    }
    static {
        System.load("jnidemo.so");
    }
}
```

**Demo.c**

```
 #include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_jniexamples_rmi_Demo_jBoolean(JNIEnv *env, jobject ob,jint dtype)
{
    printf("first demo %d" , dtype);
    return;
}
```

**Result: first demo -1579007728**

I am confused even though method signature is different, How it is calling jni method?

Comment: looks like you are just getting undefined values for the missing parameters

Comment: The method is identified by its name. You need to make sure the signatures match.

Comment: IIRR, you should include the .h header file generated by javah to make sure you have the proper function prototype

Comment: If I have two methods and with same name but different parameter , Then it will be problamatic without header.

Comment: Is it neccesser to create Header file with javah tool?

Comment: I don't think you can have two JNI methods with the same name. You need to give them different names. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637023/overload-jni-method

Comment: @Nilesh There is no other correct way to do it. The JVM and `javah` share the knowledge of exactly how a Java native method signature is mapped into C. `javah` will generate a correct header file, and it is up to you to ensure the .c file agrees with it.

Comment: @OP Use compiler flags `-Wmissing-prototypes -Werror`, it will warn you if the name/parameter-list doesn't match with the `javah`-generated function-prototype.

Comment: Pure C does not have function overloading. There can't exist two fuctions with different arguments but same name.

Answer (score 2):

C functions are identified by name only during linking and in runtime, so Java will call the function but without supplying any argument.

If you supply too few arguments when you call a C function you invoke undefined behaviour which means anything may happen.  (In your case you got a seemingly random value.)

The javah-generated  header file it will have a declaration of the function with correct signature. If you include the generated header the compiler can  compare the signature in the header with the one in the `.c` file and if they differ it will issue an error when you compile.

Comment: Thanks , I am new to Jni and C . But in such scenario How header file will help?

Comment: @Nilesh The generated header file it will have a declaration of the function with correct signature. If you include the generated header the compiler can compare the signature in the header with the one in the .c file and if they differ it will issue an error when you compile.

Answer (score 1):

Very brief scenario looks in next way. When you are calling `jBoolean()` from java, JVM notes that this method is native, and tries to find its implementation. In your case JVM constructs name of the native function by decorating of `jBoolean` with class and package name. Result is the string `Java_jniexamples_rmi_Demo_jBoolean`. Then it tries to find function with this name in the process's address space with `dlsym()`. Because of this it is crucial to load native module with this function before you try to call it. Then, if it is OK - `dlsym()` returns pointer to the function, but note that this pointer has no info about actual function signature and JVM **infers** native signature using only one that was declared in java. Then JVM invokes your native function according to inferred signature.

As result - difference between inferred signature and actual one causes undefined behavior, that may lead to very strange things, not only to random parameter values. Because of this it is a good practice - to include `javah`-generated header into your native implementations. Such header breaks compilation with error if one of your implementations has signature that differs from declared in header.

Comment: Thanks Serhio , Its cleared me about how JVM mapps java function to native function , also use of Header file